# AngularJS : Watch specific properties in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form in my angularjs application with a lot of nested objects. I need to watch some of these nested fields for change.

I have a Sales Order which has a name and an array of items. Each item has an array of sub-items and an array of schedules. I want to watch some properties which renders the "total price" dirty. For example, the Quantity, Discount, and schedule data (excluding the schedule name) require a new price to be calculated (via ajax). I want to set a flag in the root scope "_priceDirty" to show a button for refreshing the price.
The same applies when I add an item, or add a sub-item or a schedule to an item.

How would I watch these properties properly in angularjs? A deep watch on the SalesOrder is massive, and I need to check for myself which fields changed, since I don't want to enable the refresh button if only the name or description was changed. A $watchCollection on the Items would probably not work either since I want to watch only some properties inside. I could add a $watch to each field I want each time a new item/subitem/schedule is added to the list, but it seems like a lot of $watch-es (9 properties for the simplest order, around 24 properties is a normal one, see below.)

### Example

*(Changes to fields marked with a * should enable the refresh button)*

- Order name
- Total price <- (this is updated via ajax)
- Total duration <- (this is updated via ajax)
- Items

  - Item 1

    - Name
    - Description
    - Quantity *
    - SubItems

      - SubItem 1

        - Name
        - Description
        - Quantity (int) *
        - Discount (bool) *
      - SubItem 2

        - Name
        - Description
        - Quantity (int) *
        - Discount (bool) *
    - Schedules

      - Schedule 1

        - ScheduleName
        - StartDate *
        - EndDate *
        - StartTime *
        - EndTime *
      - Schedule 2

        - ScheduleName
        - StartDate *
        - EndDate *
        - StartTime *
        - EndTime *
      - Schedule 3

        - ScheduleName
        - StartDate *
        - EndDate *
        - StartTime *
        - EndTime *
  - Item 2

    - Name
    - Description
    - Quantity *
    - SubItems

      - SubItem 1

        - Name
        - Description
        - Quantity (int) *
        - Discount (bool) *
    - Schedules

      - Schedule 1

        - ScheduleName
        - StartDate *
        - EndDate *
        - StartTime *
        - EndTime *

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace angular watchers with plain event listeners. I don't know how exactly the values are getting modified, but I imagine there are some kind of input elements. So let's assume the user modifies the "quantity" input field. This generates an input event that says that the input value has changed. You can put just one event listener on the element containing all these inputs and check if the change comes from an input that interests you, and if so make the appropriate calculations, otherwise just ignore it. This way you exchange a bunch of listeners/watcher for just one watcher, but you have to filter the events. It should also solve any performance problems coming from too big number of watchers.

Comment: Thank you. This is actually the method I use in the "non-angular" version of the form. Each input that would render the price "dirty" gets a special class (.recalculateprice) and a jQuery event listener on the container listening for change events on that class. However, I feel this is not the "angular" way of doing it. Maybe ng-change is the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to the $watch

```
scope.$watch(
    function($scope) {
        return $scope.DataArr.map(function(dataInstance) {
                    return dataInstance.SomeProperty;
                });
    },
    function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal) {
            //SomeProperty was changed
        }
    });
```

A combination of the above and possibly refactoring your data structure to flatten it out a little should get you there.